# Получение доступа к элементу массива объектов

Tags: yii2

Есть массив ($client) объектов, который содержит один объект:

```
Array
(
[0] => app\models\Client Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [Name] => Макс
                [Fam] => Спивак
                [Och] => Вал
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [Name] => Макс
                [Fam] => Спивак
                [Och] => Вал
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

Как получить доступ, например к id, используя записи типа

```
$client->{'0'}->id;
$client->{0}->id;
$client->id;
$client->['0']->id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного странный вопрос. Как мы получаем элемент массива? `$arr[0]`, а как мы получаем свойство объекта? `$obj->property`.

Какой вывод? `$obj = $arr[0]`, получили объект из элемента массива. `$obj->id` получили свойство.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach ($obj as $key => value){
        echo $key . ":" . $value->id;
    }
```